# Django WeasyPrint CSS integration warning: Relative URI reference without a base URI: <link href="/static/css/bootstrap.min.css"> at line None

Tags: html, css, django, pdf, weasyprint

I want to generate reports using WeasyPrint in Django. But I don't know how to integrate the css (specifically the bootstrap css file). I am able to see the generated html. But I get a warning when I add this line to my template-

`<link href="/static/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>`

The warning is - *Relative URI reference without a base URI:  at line None*

I would like to know how to send the base URI to the template. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: why you are not using  {% static %} template tag ?

Comment: @RajaSimon That does not matter for the context of this question; `{% static %}` also produces relative URLs

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I had to add `base_url=request.build_absolute_uri()`. So the print command looks like:

```
weasyprint.HTML(string=html,base_url=request.build_absolute_uri()).write_pdf(response)
```

Comment: where does the request object come from?

Comment: @Maecky I'm probably way to late with answering this, but this question has the Django tag. I assume `request` is the variable that is passed with all Django views. If you are in a Django view and you don't have a `request` variable available, you probably need to use `self.request`.

Check out [this page in the Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.build_absolute_uri)

Comment: For further readers Weasyprint basically wants this `HTML(string=html_rendered, base_url="/app")`- that's an absolute location or URL. It should be de-hardcoded, of course.

Answer (score 0):

Adding '/' to request.build_absolute_uri() worked for me -> request.build_absolute_uri('/'):

```
weasyprint.HTML(string=html,base_url=request.build_absolute_uri('/')).write_pdf(response)
```